# Used wrong push URL pushed one repo to another by mistake; how to delete pushed branch/repo without merge?

Tags: git, github, git-bash, git-remote

Question: is there a way to delete remote branches without merging them in?

Background:
We had a third party do some work for us they use GitHub and we do also

So I pulled from there repo and pushed to ours. Unfortunately, I pushed to the wrong repo.
So now we have a project with this other project in it.

We do not really want to merge in all the changes and delete them and have the history remain.
I would just like to delete this branch(push).

I have tried 
-git push origin --delete branchName
 (of course this will only work if its merged in.)

It looks like the only way to delete a nonmerged branch is with -D 
-git branch -D branchname
(but this only works on the local repo)

is there a way to delete branches without merging them on a remote repository
or any other way to clean this mess up? (one repo pushed to another no merge)

Answer (score 1):

```
git push origin :branchName
```

always works for me.

Comment: This is perfectly correct, but just for the record: the syntax for pushing branches is git push remote-name local-branch:remote-branch. For deletion, the idea is that you're pushing *nothing* into remote-branch, updating remote-branch into nothing. Knowing the logic behind it may help people remember it.

Comment: @SáT: thanks, I didn't know that. I just treated it as Git magic.

Comment: I can push to the remote fine but to delete this branch and everything with it without merging is the problem.

Maybe I am missing something here?

Comment: @user1886208: maybe you're missing the colon before branchName? :) Try it, it should work. It's an awkward syntax for sure, but that's the way it is. If it doesn't work, you may try git push origin : branchname --force, but it shouldn't be needed. Also, you may want to check out [this](http://git-scm.com/book/ch3-5.html) and [this](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data) -- the latter contains dangerous stuff, so be careful (you may want to test these out in a dummy repo).

Comment: @user1886208: is there an error message? What happens when you try it?

Comment: $ git branch -D master  ->  
Deleted branch master (was 16bc001).  ->  
$ git branch push :master  ->  
Fatal: Not a valid object name: ':master'

Comment: @user1886208: that's `git push`, not `git branch push`.

Comment: Still no luck getting error -> remote: error: refusing to delete the current branch: refs/heads/master To git@github.com:***/***.git ! [remote rejected] master (deletion of the current branch prohibited) error: failed to push some refs to git@github.com:***/***.git'